# Tweaking the silent mode in Inno-Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Currently I use an external argument in this way:

```
myapp.exe \SILENCE \LICENSE=mylicense
```

and then in the script:

```
[INI]
    Filename: mydefine.ini; Section: "General"; Key: "License"; String: "{param:LICENSE}"
```

The question is: I'd like to support both situations:

- When "\License" argument is specified - I'd like to use the
  "Filename" statement above
- When "\License" argument is omitted - I prefer to skip the line above in INI (since it could be that this line is already configured and I do not want to update it with a blank value

Is that possible to distinguish? How to?

Thx

Comment: When you're posting questions about code, you really should take the time to get the details correct.  The command line would actually be `/SILENT /LICENSE=whatever`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply compare if the parameter isn't empty, to avoid writing a blank value.

```
[INI]
Filename: mydefine.ini; Section: "General"; Key: "License"; String: "{param:LICENSE}"; Check: HasLicense

[Code]
function HasLicense(): Boolean;
begin
    Result := ExpandConstant('{param:LICENSE}') <> '';
end;
```